# Excel - Duplicate rows from one sheet onto multiple sheets

Tags: excel, split, duplicates, rows

What I am trying to do is to have the first five rows of one specific sheet in a workbook show up as the first five rows of all sheets in the workbook. So when I change anything on that one specific sheet, the changes are reflected on all sheets. I know how to split a sheet but while that is close, it is not what I need. I do need something similar to a split but I need to have the split be a different sheet, if that is possible. I am using Excel from Office 15.

Comment: Probably doable with VBA and the `Worksheet_Change` event.

Comment: Maybe just a formula in the first five rows of the other sheets, equivalent to, for example `=A1:Z5`. (*and then protect those cells so they can't be changed inadvertently*).

Comment: Thank you both for the rapid responses!  I'll check into those.